# IntelliJ - Go back and forth in one split view only

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

I am able to use the shortcut to go back and forth if I only have one view.

But sometimes when I open a split view to work on some specific file. If in this split view I ever go to the file opened in the main view. Then my cursor is moving to the main view, which annoys me.

Is there a way that I can just move back and forth in the particular view. Or in another way, is there a way for me to work on a file in a separate window completely independent. Like having two IDE openings same project.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, Is there any way you can provide an example, or be more specific?

Comment: Say I have three files A, B, C. and my split view 1 and 2. view 1 displaying A and view 2 displaying B now. I'm focusing on view 1 with A and then switch to B file, then switch to C file. And then I use shortcut to navigate Back, when it is about to go back the the B file at view 1, the focus goes to view 2 because view 2 has the B opening. I want to avoid this `smart` behaviour.